# TYPO3 multidomains for developing

Tags: dns, typo3

I use a developer domain (domain.com.dev) for my local installation. For that I created three domain records for one domain:

```
domain.com -> redirect to http://www.domain.com
www.domain.com
domain.com.dev
```

But to get domain.com.dev working I have to deactivate the first two one. Will be there an other solution to do that with constants or pageTSconfig?

#### edited:

Using now htaccess-redirect for non www.

```
# Redirect non-www to www and ignore dev subdomain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(www\.|dev\.).* [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Above I forgot another subdomain, so the domain records now as followed:

First tree:

```
www.domain.com
dev.domain.com
```

Second tree:

```
sub.domain.com
dev.sub.domain.com
```

But if I call now dev.domain.com the links are parsed as www.domain.com. Before I used baseURL. Than I read somwhere, I can't remember where, that baseURL is outdated.

But if I don't use baseURL this trick will not work. And with sub.domain.com it will not work anyway.

#### edited II

I' have now following two domain records for the domain sub.domain.com:

```
sub.domain.com
dev.sub.domain.com
```

If only one is activated, the internal links will be like `href="home.html"`, if the second is activated they are `href="http://sub.domain.com/home.html"`. But I'm currently on the domain dev.sub.domain.com.

Cause I have more domains in one installation I need these records. But how can I get rid of this prefixed URLs?

If TYPO3 prepends the domain to the links, baseURL will be useless...

Comment: Why should baseURL be outdated? Is is used very often and works great with realurl and multi domain instances of TYPO3. So no need to avoid it in my eyes. Of course, you have to use a conditional setup then, like in Björns answer if you have several different domains pointing to the same page/tree. If there are multiple root pages, set the baseURL there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience it is not a good idea to structure it that way. It is much easier using `dev.domain.com` for your dev system and then add this to the `hosts` file to point to your local system.

The non-www to www redirect should also be made with a `.htaccess`, not within TYPO3 (performance). To solve the problem with your current structure you could try to remove the `domain.com` from the list and do then redirect as mentioned. Then the `.com.dev` should also work.

Comment: The hint to redirect htaccess will be a good one. I edited the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly you need to setup a baseUrl based on the new domains.

This can be done as follows in TypoScript:

```
[globalString = ENV:HTTP_HOST=dev.domain.com]
        config.baseUrl = http://dev.domain.com/
[globalString = ENV:HTTP_HOST=dev.sub.domain.com]
        config.baseUrl = http://dev.sub.domain.com/
[end]
```

Next, if you use RealUrl or CoolUri, you will also need to create domain-records for these in the Typo3 backend.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I think I've got it now. Non www redirected by htaccess, www.* and dev.* domain records to find the current domain tree, and baseURL conditions to stay in current domain. Have you also a hint for me which will be better to use: baseURL or absRefPrefix. I worked a long time with baseURL and it was ok for me. I just avoid absRefPrefix cause I think it generates more chars for loading.

Comment: I'd say use baseUrl, it works everytime. This is because absRefPrefix is not respected by all extensions..

Comment: It's not possible to check both answers :( so I do the first.

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of some help :)

Comment: I have still a problem with this configuration :( edited the question.

Comment: Have you checked your domain records? There's a checkbox there that enables prefixing the baseurl.

Comment: No, this option is deactivated.